# Java error: The method setParent(IndexNode) is undefined for the type DocumentIndex and type IndexNode

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, undefined, getter-setter

I realize I'm a novice. I am just learning to program. I am using Eclipse. I am programming a binary tree, with two classes: IndexNode, which is just a node and Document Index, with is the tree. The other is however it I get the two messages at the same time for on each one of my setters and getters. Both classes are in the same package. I let Eclipse recreate the setters (in the code case I posted) and still gives me the same errors. Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

-The method setParent(IndexNode) is undefined for the type DocumentIndex
-The method setParent(IndexNode) is undefined for the type IndexNode

The code for the DocumentIndex class:

```
public class DocumentIndex{

IndexNode root;
private IndexNode currentNode; 
private IndexNode newNode;

public DocumentIndex(){

    root = null;
}

public void addValue(String word){

    if( newNode != root ){

         newNode.setWord(word);

         addRoot();
    }
}

public void addRoot(){



    if (root == null){

        root = newNode;
        currentNode = root;
            currentNode = setParent(currentNode); 
    }   *//I get these errors for all my getters and setters*
}
```

Here is my IndexNode class code:

```
public class IndexNode {

private String word; 
private IndexNode left = null;
private IndexNode right = null; 
private IndexNode parent;

public IndexNode( String word, IndexNode left, IndexNode right, IndexNode parent ){

    this.word = word;
    this.left = left; 
    this.right = right;
    this.parent = parent;

}

public void setWord( String word ){

    this.word = word; 
}

public String getWord(){

    return word; 
}

public void getLeft( IndexNode left ){

    this.left = left;
}

public void getRight( IndexNode right ){

    this.right = right; 
}

public IndexNode setLeft(){

    return left;
}

public IndexNode setRight(){

    return right; 
}

public void getParent( IndexNode parent ){

    this.parent = parent; 
}
```

}

Comment: where is `setParent(IndexNode)`???

Comment: In your code doesm;t exist setParent function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have a lot of mistakes :

```
currentNode = setParent(currentNode);
```

Setters are used for setting some values to object ,for purpose of getting values we use getters.For getting value of current node first generate a getter for it in Indexnode class.So for further clarification I will replace your try to call setter with try to calling a getter method.

Java's basic rules is , that If you want to use other class's method you need to call its method using its object.So:

```
currentNode = getParent();
```

Will not work as getParent method is defined for Indexnode class ,and you are calling it in other calss.

If you want to call that ,you should create Indexnode's object first:

```
Indexnode obj1=new Indexnode(); //creating an object
```

and then call it's method using it's object.

```
currentobj=obj1.getparent(); //calling getParent() method which will return you parent's value
```

Edit:

> **Indexnode obj1=new Indexnode();**     //new Indexnode() -- expecting empty construtor

will not work ,As you have created a parameterised constructor,In that case jvm does't create a default constructor for you.you will have to create a default empty construtor for it.AS we are calling empty constructor while doing Indexnode obj1=new Indexnode();

Comment: Thank you! I have gone back and made most of changes suggested, however, when I try to initialize the IndexNode Object in the DocumentIndex class I get these two errors: The method setParent(IndexNode) is undefined for the type DocumentIndex and the constructor to the new node is underdefined.

Comment: HAve you used exact syntax Indexnode obj1=new Indexobj1();Does eclipse show's any error on this?

Comment: You don't need to call setter,As you want get value of current node, for that purpose we have getters,Setters are used for setting values into object

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Yes I did enter it in that exact syntax: IndexNode currentNode = new IndexNode(); I get the message - The constructor IndexNode() is undefined. I tried initializing it before and got the same message.

Comment: Create a default constructor in your Indexnode class.

Comment: I have explained reason in edit,we are calling empty constructor,as you have created a parametrised constructor ,so jvm does't Create it for you.It's programmer's responsibility to create it.

Comment: Thank you Abhijeet! You figured it out. I forgot the no-arg constructor in the Index Class. You are awesome! In the mean time I learn something. It also forced me to rethink my code. Thank you everyone!

Comment: You are most welcome bro,Its good to know that I was able to help you anyhow.You can mark answer as correct, so it can help others also :)

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly, you want to call a function that you did not implement:

`setParent(IndexNode)` does not exist!

Implement it, then you can call it. Should be obvious.